# Subset of the event {$i$ aces in $i$ cards} and its probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

As far as I'm aware, $A$ is a subset of $B$ if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$ for all $x\in A$. If so, how could this statement (please see the image below) say the event {4 aces in 4 cards} was a subset of the event {$i$ aces in $i$ cards} $i$ = 1, 2, 3? Obviously, the element 1S of the event {1C, 1D, 1H, 1S} didn't belong to the event {1C, 1D, 1H}, thus the statement was incorrect, or I misunderstood what it meant by {$i$ aces in $i$ cards}? Also, how could one derive the probability of the event {$i$ aces in $i$ cards} as 4 choose $i$ divides 52 choose $i$? Could you please help explain in simple terms (with simple examples) the logic of all this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability calculation is pretty straightforward. The sample space is we choose $i$ cards out of $52$, the interested event is we choose $i$ cards from the aces. So, the ratio makes sense. For the subset, it should have been $i=1,2,3,4$ instead of $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Thanks for your simple explanation, @gunes. However, there's a difference between your statement and the one from the screenshot: {$i$ cards from $i$ aces} vs. {$i$ aces from $i$ cards}. Could you please confirm whether {$i$ aces from $i$ cards} was a typo or both statements are equivalent, that is, {$i$ cards from $i$ aces} == {$i$ aces from $i$ cards}.

Comment: The probability I calculate is $i$ aces in $i$ cards. But, the numerator is the number of ways we choose those $i$ cards from the *aces*, i.e. ${4\choose i}$.